# Sort Sql Query by Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-date-functions

I am having a sql query as :

```
select dateName(month, DateAccessed) "Month"
, count(1) totalVisits
, count(distinct l.userName) UsersVisit
from and where clause goes here
group by dateName(monthDateAccessed)
order by Month
```

The output I get is

```
Month   totalVisits   UsersVisit
April         100       25
February      200       35
July          300       45
March         400       55
May           500       65
```

But the ouput I want is in the order of:

```
February      200       35
March         400       55
April         100       25
May           500       65
July          300       45
```

How can I get this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use either `month(DateAccessed)` or `datepart(month, DateAccessed)` to extract the month number and use that in the `order by` clause. You will however have to add it to the `group by` clause too:

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(month, DateAccessed) "Month", 
    COUNT(1) totalVisits, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT l.userName) UsersVisit 
FROM and where clause goes here
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(dateaccessed), 
    DATENAME(month, DateAccessed)
ORDER BY 
    MONTH(dateaccessed);
```

If your data holds data for more than one year you should include the year in the group- and order by clauses (and select statement) if you don't already make sure you only get data from one year in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the `ORDER BY` clause to order by the month number of the `DateAccessed`:

```
select dateName(month, DateAccessed) "Month"
, count(1) totalVisits
, count(distinct l.userName) UsersVisit
from and where clause goes here
group by dateName(monthDateAccessed)
order by Month(DateAccessed)
```

Comment: I get an error : **is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

Answer (score 0):

You are ordering by DATENAME, which is a string. Try ordering by DATEPART (an Integer) instead:

```
select dateName(month, DateAccessed) "Month"
, count(1) totalVisits
, count(distinct l.userName) UsersVisit
from and where clause goes here
group by dateName(monthDateAccessed), DATEPART(mm, dateAccessed)
order by DATEPART(mm, dateAccessed)
```

Comment: I get an error : **is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause**.

Comment: Sorry I neglected to include the calculated field in the answer, try my update.

Answer (score -1):

Add one column  `month(DateAccessed) as MonthNo` and set this column in order by.

```
select dateName(month, DateAccessed) "Month", month(DateAccessed) as MonthNo,
, count(1) totalVisits
, count(distinct l.userName) UsersVisit
from and where clause goes here
group by dateName(monthDateAccessed)
order by MonthNo
```

Comment: Adding a column would break his `GROUP BY`, and is overall not necessary to include additional columns to change the sort order.

Comment: I don't think so, because we have added function with already used column :)

Comment: Also, T-SQL does not permit the use of an alias defined in the same scope for the order by.